Transformation under coordinate transformation of scalar perurbation of FLRW metric
For the past few days I've been studying perturbation in cosmology. More specifically I am now busy with chapter 6 in Dodelson's Modern cosmology. In this book the perturbed FLRW metric which only considers scalar perturbations is given by
$$g_{00} = -(1+2A) \quad g_{0i} = -a\partial_iB \quad g_{ij} = a^2(\delta_{ij}[1+2D]-2\partial_i\partial_jE)$$
The book now states that under the following coordinate transformation
$$t \rightarrow \hat{t} = t + \zeta(t, \vec{x}) \quad x^i \rightarrow \hat{x}^i = x^i + \partial_i\xi(t,\vec{x})$$
I am now wondering how the scalar perturbation $A,B,D,E$ transform under this coordinate transformation. I was able to find how this work for $A$ and $B$ however I do not know how to do this for the scalars $D$ and $E$. For $A$ and $B$ is made use of the transformation law of the metric. I tried doing the same for $E$ and $D$ but failed. Is there another way on how to determine how these scalars evolve? The answer should be the following
$$E \rightarrow E + \xi \quad \quad D \rightarrow D - H\zeta.$$

I think there is some information missing. Do you know how the metric looks like after the coordinate transformation?
